# What is the term which encompasses accents, umlauts, etc?

Tags: single-word-requests, alphabet, diacritics

Is there a term that covers [grave](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) and [acute](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent) accents, [umlauts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umlaut), [cedillas](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cedilla), [tildes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde) and all other characters that can be added to normal letters.

I have come across the word [*diacritics*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic). But this seems to include things like commas and apostrophes.

Comment: It's the first link on 3 of those wiki pages.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Heh, I didn't look at the links. In that case, it probably is general reference, you're right.

Comment: Four of those five Wikipedia pages are in the category [Alphabetic diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Alphabetic_diacritics) (see bottom of the page). The fifth is a disambiguation page, but the intended page is also in [Alphabetic diacritics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Alphabetic_diacritics).

Comment: I did see the word "diacritic", but I had understood it to include commas, etc. So I thought it was not the correct level of abstraction. Thanks to onomatomaniak for explaining.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I believe the term you're looking for is [***diacritic***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diacritic).

Comment: It seems that a diacritic also includes "apostrophes", "commas", etc. I'm only interested in characters that can be added to normal letters.

Comment: Commas are not diacritical in English. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma#Diacritical_usage. (Apostrophes aren't either; they're diacritical in languages whose scripts use them in the form of an "accent", not a punctuation mark.)

Comment: Adding a comma to individual letters- how weird! Oh ok, well I guess it works then. Thanks!

Comment: No problem. (Though I imagine this question will be closed in any case as general reference.)

Comment: It's looking that way. Unfairly in my opinion. You have to know the word already to know what to look for. Ho hum!

Comment: You might save the question by rewording it to address your confusion about commas, etc.

Comment: I tried. But alas the band-wagon was already rolling.